# how to add a new line in a config file after the last variable data set

Tags: powershell, variables

I want to add a line to a series of cfg files in subfolders after a variable line.

```
some text ...
light.0 = some text
light.1 = some text
...
light.n = some text
... some text
```

Each text file has a varied n<sup>th</sup> data line.

All I want to add is the (n+1)<sup>th</sup> data line after those n<sup>th</sup> lines in each cfg files in subfolders.

```
light.(n+1) = some text
```

I want to carry out this task in PowerShell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a script writing service. Please, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Show us the code on where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explain why you fail to complete the task. Someone would help you…

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get all the config files, and loop over them
Get-ChildItem "d:\test" -Recurse -Include *.cfg | ForEach-Object {

    # Output a progress message
    Write-Host "Processing file: $_"

    # Make a backup copy of the file, forcibly overwriting one if it's there
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_ -Destination "$_+.bak" -Force

    # Read the lines in the file
    $Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $_ -Raw

    # A regex which matches the last "light..." line
    #  - line beginning with light.
    #  - with a number next (capture the number)
    #  - then equals, text up to the end of the line
    #  - newline characters
    #  - not followed by another line beginning with light
    $Regex = '^light.(?<num>\d+) =.*?$(?![\r\n]+^light)'

    # A scriptblock to calculate the regex replacement
    # needs to output the line which was captured
    # and calculat the increased number
    # and output the new line as well
    $ReplacementCalculator = {

        param($RegexMatches)

        $LastLine = $RegexMatches[0].Value
        $Number = [int]$RegexMatches.groups['num'].value

        $NewNumber = $Number + 1

        "$LastLine`nlight.$NewNumber = some new text"

    }

    # Do the replacement and insert the new line
    $Content = [regex]::Replace($Content, $Regex, $ReplacementCalculator, 'Multiline')

    # Update the file with the new content
    $Content | Set-Content -Path $_

}
```

<sub>(* I'm sure I read that somewhere)</sub>

Assumes the 'light' lines are contiguous with no blocks of other text in the middle, and that they are ordered, with the highest number being last. You might have to play with the line endings `\r\n` in the regex and `n in the replacement text, to make them match up.

<sub>(Sorry about the regex)</sub>

Comment: light lines are contiguous following one after the other without any spaces or lines in between, each occupying one line proper just like I described in my question text above :
`light.1 = some text`
`light.2 = some text`
`light.3 = some text`
`light.4 = some text`
`light.5 = some text`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`light.n = some text`
thank you. 
however, I see that it fails to add any new line tp the .cfg files in subfolders.

Comment: it does not create a .bak file in the sub-folders, either. yes, there is a space in each line between the number and equal sign ie light.17 = some text .there are also other lines of data above and below those light data group in each of the .cfg files just as I depicted in my original question text above.

Comment: What if your subfolders have wildcard characters in their paths? I've edited my answer to make Get-Content and Copy-Item use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`, maybe that will help?

Comment: folder path where .cfg files are located has neither wildcards nor spaces. I had no sooner run the powershell than a cmd-like window popped up with some red codeing characters on the traditional black screen for as short as half a second or so, denoting something actually goes wrong while processing the code.

Comment: I'll try omitting the processing file message part.

Comment: I can't really guess anything else helpful unless you can open powershell and run the script by typing it, and see the errors. Are you on PowerShell v2 (Server 2008)? I don't think that had support for the `-LiteralPath` parameters. But I can't think why it's not getting files in subfolders then.

Comment: just updated my PS security settings. it works as a charm now. I thank you very much for taking your time. it would be even better if an empty line could be placed right after this newly added (n+1)th line.

Comment: Ohh, security settings? I wasn't thinking anything along those lines at all. Good find.  You could put another newline (\`n) at the end of the replacement line `"$LastLine\`nlight.$NewNumber = some new text\`n"` to add an empty line.